# Keep / Replace empty values in getall() with Scrapy

Tags: python-3.x, web-scraping, scrapy

i want to scrape some element from a website, and i have to maintain the order of the values.
So for example:

```
def parse(self, response):
    id_num = response.css('td:nth-child(1)::text').getall()
    issued_at = response.css(
        '.align-center.xcrud-current::text').getall()
    exchange = response.css(
        '.xcrud-current+ .align-center::text').getall()
    base_currency = response.css(
        '.align-center:nth-child(4)::text').getall()
    coin = response.css(
        '.align-center:nth-child(5)::text').getall()
    direction = response.css(
        '.align-center:nth-child(6)::text').getall()
    ask = response.css(
        '.align-right:nth-child(7)::text').getall()
    target = response.css(
        '.align-right:nth-child(8)::text').getall()
    highest = response.css(
        '.align-right:nth-child(9)::text').getall()
    lowest = response.css(
        '.align-right:nth-child(10)::text').getall()
    status = response.css(
        'td:nth-child(11)::text').getall()
    close_time = response.css(
        '.align-right~ .align-center::text').getall()
    dca_level = response.css(
        '.align-right:nth-child(13)::text').getall()

    for id_num, issued_at, exchange, base_currency, coin, direction, ask, target, highest, lowest, status, close_time, dca_level in\
            zip(id_num, issued_at, exchange, base_currency, coin, direction, ask, target, highest, lowest, status, close_time, dca_level):

        yield{
            'Id': id_num,
            'Issued At': issued_at,
            'Exchange': exchange,
            'Base Currency': base_currency,
            'Coin': coin,
            'Direction': direction,
            'Ask': ask,
            'Target': target,
            'Highest': highest,
            'Lowest': lowest,
            'Status': status,
            'Close Time': close_time,
            'DCA Level': dca_level
        }
```

Basically, the IDs are taken correctly as they are all present, while close_time is not always present, and therefore the output CSV is truncated.If I don't use ::text, the elements are all taken.

For example:

```
Id,Issued At,Exchange,Base Currency,Coin,Direction,Ask,Target,Highest,Lowest,Status,Close Time,DCA Level
499762,01/12/2020 08:46:40,binance,USDT,CTK,LONG,1.208900000000,1.231802400000,9.975000000000,9.927000000000,open,01/12/2020 08:25:00,0
499837,01/12/2020 08:46:17,kraken,USD,AUD,LONG,0.737670000000,0.745784370000,0.000003860000,0.000003840000,open,01/12/2020 08:30:00,0
```

What I want is to keep / replace empty values.

Comment: I don't think you can use the `getall()` but I am not sure without seeing an example of your `response` text. The thing is, the issue you are having is when, for example: the `<id_num>.getall()` returns 10 elements, but the `<exchange>.getall()` returns 9. Well, you don't know when the where the missing element was. It could have been the first, in the middle or at the end. You need to "walk" over the elements and look for certain attributes instead of doing `getall()`

Comment: Yes exactly! Do you know any method to solve the problem? Should I go through these lists?

Comment: So, I would need to see the source you are parsing to give a specific example... but a generic one is this: I do not have any experience with `scappy` but it looks like it can represent the DOM as python objects. This means that you can "walk" along the page and build you structure as you walk. This will allow you to have you `if this field doesn't exist, return "blank"` and any other conditions you see fit. Does that make sense? In particular, I would look at the elements containing the elements with the class `align-center` and iterate over those.

Comment: It could be solved in this way, but I was thinking of a less "pythonic" and more "Scrapy" solution. Well, i'll wait someone else to answer

Comment: If you want someone to answer, you need to show data. Currently your problem is just that you are using `zip()` with uneven lists. Your lists are uneven because you are using a CSS selector to select elements matching a particular pattern. By definition, since sometimes the values are empty, they won't be selected by the CSS selector. ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to rewrite your `parse` callback to work with a single item:

```
def parse(self, response):
    for item in response.css('your_epxression to_get list_of_items'):
        id_num = item.css('td:nth-child(1)::text').get()
        issued_at = item.css(
        '.align-center.xcrud-current::text').get()
        ...
        yield {'Id': id_num, 'Issued At': issued_at, ...}
```